# Java index out of bounds error - missing entries

Tags: java, indexing

I'm trying to parse a csv file. A typical line looks like this:

```
7,118.2722833,98.61084463,94.36895546,,
```

The problem I'm having is that when I split the line, I'm only getting an array length of 4. I would like to have the fifth and sixth elements of the array return null, but I'm getting an index out of bounds error.

Here is a reduced version of the code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileName"));
String line = "";
String[] datum = new String[6];

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    datum = line.split(",");

    if (datum[5] != "") {
        //some statements
    }
}
```

Any idea why it's ignoring the last 2 commas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @jlordo Sure, `!=` vs `!equals` is an issue here, but the main question is how to use `split` to keep the trailing empty fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `split` method without any arguments will discard any trailing `null` elements.  Pass a negative `limit` to [`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), and it will return an array with trailing `null` elements intact.

```
datum = line.split(",", -1);
```

Also, don't use `!=` to see if it's the empty string; use

```
if (!("".equals(datum[5]))) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Array index starts from 0, if you want 5th element you need to do `datum[4]` instead of `datum[5]`

```
7 --------------0
118.2722833-----1
98.61084463-----2
94.36895546-----3,
 ----------------4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading about the `limit` parameter to the method [`java.lang.String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)